# Why all resume templates showing PDF rendering error?

Tags: compiling, templates, compilation-error, rendering

I heard about overleaf and wanted to try it for building a resume. Problem is that whatever template I choose, it doesn't show me a preview on the right side. There is always some error and it shows me the message

> PDF Rendering Error Something went wrong while rendering this PDF

I saw the logs. But don't understand any of them. I tried many templates but none of them show the preview on the right side. All show the same error. I included a photo.

Comment: Hi Shahab --- Welcome. Please, think a bit about our position here: you are basically saying you have an error, without giving any example of code at all.  It is impossible to even start to guess. Please,  read about [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and provide some context.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of overleaf? The image is missing in your question ...